# Set profile on VSCode to have 3 terminals at the same time by default

Tags: ubuntu, visual-studio-code, terminal

Whenever I use VScode for my projects, I always open 3 separate terminals in the editor itself.

One for commands (Zsh), one to have a Ruby console (irb) and one for the server (puma). Each of them with a different color and icon.

[image]

My question is... Can I configure the VSCode so that always by default the 3 are launched with their respective colors and icons?

For now I always have to configure them by hand every time I start VSCode.

I have tryed to change the settings.json file, but I don't know what params it supports... :(

Comment: I dont see a way to do that - perhaps submit a feature request https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues

Comment: if anyone is interested in implementing this feature, support is appreciated. Just click on the link and leave a like
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/165040